# jQuery drop function for appended elements

Tags: jquery-ui

When I `drag` an element to a `droppable` area, it sends a `socket` to the server. Whenever I `append` a new element to the page, the `drop: function() {}` does not trigger when the appended element is dropped, it only works once the page has been refreshed, although the `drag` function works.

**question**

Is there a way to bind the `drop` function to the appending elements?

**code**

```
var UI = {
    droppedArea: $('.dropArea'),
    initialArea: $('#init-area')
};

UI.droppedArea.droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this),
        /* Rest of the code */
        socket.emit('move', data);
   }
});

// Element appended like this
function newItem(data) {
   var html = '<li>'+data.content+'</li>';
   UI.initialArea.append(html);
}

// From the server
socket.on('new', function(data) {
   newItem(data);
});
```

Comment: is this a typo? `UI.dropArea`.. it should be `UI.droppedArea`

Comment: yes it is. will fix it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why.

Under the `drop: function()`, I had an `accept:` option, which value were DOM elements, with a type of class, stored in a variable.

Therefore, any appended elements were not referenced by the variable, so they were not being captured by the function

```
var UI = {
   var item = $('.the_item')
}

drop: function() {
    accept: UI.item,
}
```